# How to send an email in SSIS to recipient based on lookup table?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, event-handling

I am wanting to create a Send Mail Task in SSIS inside of an event handler, for when a file in a for each loop does not process as intended. The file is in .xlsx format. In the file name (or in the rows) will be an Account ID that I want to use to reference a table. That table has two columns, AccountID and email address. The email address is where I want to send the email when that file fails to be processed.

I am relatively new to creating these kind of tasks in SSIS so I will need some help. I am mostly worried about how to reference the table in the task... thinking I may need to have multiple steps? Let me know if you need more context or information, and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There's a lot packed into this "somewhat" simple looking question. What failed? This determines the "event" that you are trying to find and whether you are inside the dataflow to get info from inside the file. Next, where is account found? Is it in the filename (ALL the time)? Do you already have that in a variable? More information is needed if you really want an effective answer.

Answer (score 2):

From information provided you have to use ssis script task or send email task with variables getting the emailAddress from the reference table.

```
//SSIS script task
        public void Main()
        {
            SmtpClient varSMTPClient;

            string varEmailFrom = Dts.Variables["$Project::projectParameterEmailFrom"].Value.ToString();// readonly variable
            string varEmailTo = Dts.Variables["$Project::projectParameterEmailTo"].Value.ToString();// readonly variable

            MailMessage varHTMLMAIL = new MailMessage(varEmailFrom, varEmailTo);
            varHTMLMAIL.IsBodyHtml = true;
            varHTMLMAIL.Subject = "SSIS send e-mail";

            varHTMLMAIL.Body = "e-mail body text";
            varSMTPClient = new SmtpClient("SMTP Servername");
            varSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            varSMTPClient.Send(varHTMLMAIL);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: I think I follow somewhat.. but not sure how to tie in the script necessary on the SQL side. Like I will need to use an ID field from the file to lookup into the table and get the destination email address.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to this issue:

> I am mostly worried about how to reference the table in the task

1. Get account number into a variable some how. If it is in filename (this is best target for string manipulation.
2. Add a execute SQL, and set the SQL to "select email from [your table] where account = ?"
3. Set result set to single row
4. Parameter Map you variable from Step 1
5. Map your result to a "email varaible"
6. Use that email variable to send mail somehow (either send Mail task or script task or SQL task through DB Mail). My preference is c# script task as you have much more control.